# Setting link text in front of overlapping images?

Tags: html, css, z-index, overlap

I have a footer for my website, in which there are links which images below them, and both separate divs containing these overlap. Where the images and links overlap, the links are not-clickable.

Extracting the relevant code and making a JSFiddle out of it might take a little time, so I'm posting images, and I hope someone can help me out based on these:

The `footer_info` div containing the links:

[image]

The `footer_row_0` div containing the images:

[image]

For my scenario, the following links do not work:

```
Privacy Policy
Terms & Conditions
Site Map
Affiliates
Specials
Wish List
Newsletter
```

I already tried setting `z-index: 10` for `footer_info`, but it didn't solve the problem. And if I set a negative `z-index` value for `footer_row_0`, the row disappears.

`footer_info` computed CSS:

```
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-image: none;
background-position: 50% 0%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
clear: both;
color: rgb(84, 84, 84);
display: block;
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
height: 149px;
line-height: 18px;
margin-bottom: -75px;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 20px;
width: 980px;
z-index: auto;
```

`footer_row_0` computed CSS:

```
color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
display: block;
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
height: 150px;
line-height: 18px;
position: relative;
width: 980px;
z-index: 0;
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright guys, after spending 1-2 hours on this, I've managed to find the a solution. Firstly, thanks to @Broken Heart for his help, because my answer is partially based on his. Also, I'm not making my own answer to get points or something (don't really care about them), but I'm only doing so, so that other people also stuck on this issue can see what the solution was.

Okay, so I firstly applied this CSS for **footer_info** div:

```
#footer_info {
    z-index: 1 !important;
    position: relative;
}
```

For the small silhouette images, I had a CSS class **silhouette** too. So I added the following to **silhouette** CSS class:

```
.silhouette {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

With these two modifications, I was able to get the links to click, and the silhouette images were also fully seen.

Answer (score 1):

In the **footer_info** use the z-index with the `position`:

Add this css in the **footer_info** div:

```
position: absolute;
z-index:999 !important;
```

z-index worked with the position property.

Comment: Tried it. Two problems: When I only apply `position: absolute;`, it moves all the elements below upwards, filling `footer_info`s space almost completely. Both div's contents are visible at this point. When I apply `z-index:999 !important;` as well, `footer_info` does come in front, but it also brings the white background of `footer_info` in front as well, so `footer_row_0` contents (which are overlapping in the background, are no longer visible.

Comment: @Ahmad Try with the `position: relative;`

Comment: I've found the solution, and have posted it as my own answer. But thanks for your help, as your answer kind of started me off.

Answer (score 0):

```
footer_info {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-image: none;
  background-position: 50% 0%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  clear: both;
  color: rgb(84, 84, 84);
  position: relative; /* or absolute */
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 149px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-bottom: -75px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 980px;
  z-index: 9999;

footer_row_0 {
  color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 18px;
  position: relative;
  width: 980px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```